# Parse issue expected expression xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

hey guys i'am new in Xcode i'am trying to develop a game using unity , in order to uploaded in app store i had to go trhough Xcode but constantly keep showing me this error "parse issue expected expression "

Comment: Did you try changing compile source in build settings ?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some brace-mismatch in the method before this one.